# How to use Web View's loadFinished event using angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am showing a webview in my app that takes a little bit to load and instead of just showing a blank screen I want to show a progress indicator that will go away and show the web view when the web view is done loading. I tried it this way:

```
<GridView *ngIf="!loading">
    <WebView src="~/pages/tripAdvisor/reviewView.html" (loadFinishedEvent)="pageLoaded()"></WebView>
</GridView>

<ActivityIndicator *ngIf="loading" busy="true" width="100" height="100"></ActivityIndicator>
```

but the page loaded function is never called in my component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **(loadFinished)="pageLoaded()"** instead of **loadFinishedEvent**

Comment: And in your component class use **loadFinished(event: LoadEventData) {...}**

Comment: This is the correct answer. If anyone is trying to do what I did, you can't use ngIf to hide a loading webview becasue ngif wont create the webview until its conditions are true. So in this case i hid the webview by setting the visibility tag like this: `visibility="{{loading ? 'collapsed' : 'visible'}}"`